# Unity скольжение по склону

Tags: unity3d

На игроке установлен Rigidbody. Можно ли как-то через скрипт проверить, скользит ли игрок по склону в данный момент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас правильно настроена физика, то можно просто проверить его скорость:

```
Debug.Log(rigidBody.velocity.magnitude > 0);
```

Если длина вектора скорости не равна 0, значит объект движется.

---

Если в вашей игре объект может двигаться не только по склону вниз, то можно сделать еще проще: нужно проверять только **y** составляющую скорости:

```
Debug.Log(rigidBody.velocity.y < 0);
```

Именно меньше 0, т.к. при спуске со склона объект движется *вниз* по оси y.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @АнтонТерешкин, лучшая благодарность - отметке "правильности ответа" :)